# Bootstrap 3 carousel lazyload plugin not work With jQuery 1.11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I add plugin for bootstrap carousel image lazyload like this:

CSS:

```
.carousel .item {
    background-color: #000;
}
.carousel .loading {
    width:46px;
    height:46px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    background:#000 url(http://media.gillettevenus.com/Common/Assets/Images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
    margin:-23px 0px 0px -23px;
    z-index:100;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

i action `lazy-src` not work and bootstrap carousel only show first image in jQuery 1.11. But in jQuery 1.8 Worked. how do can i fix this ?!

Not Work [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BoWw/51fLLtq2/1/)

Worked [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BoWw/51fLLtq2/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) for this. The nice thing about lazySizes is that lazySizes works as a self-initializing component. This means it works seamlessly with any kind of image (and other) lazyloading without additional JS configuration. No matter whether you are using a carousel, a mega menu, infinite scroll and so on. This dramatically helps for separation of concerns. For example in case you are switching from bootstrap carousel to slick slider or you have some other larger images on your website and want to lazyload them, the only script you need is lazySizes.

After adding lazySizes to your document, you simply need to add the class `lazyload` and a `data-src` attribute.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
    class="lazyload"
    data-src="image.jpg"
    alt="my image" />
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/g21qL7xd/embedded/result/ (without progress spinner)
- http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/99b7tshc/embedded/result/ (with progress spinner)

Also note, that you should add the [intrinsic ratio pattern](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes#specifying-image-dimensions-minimizing-reflows-and-avoiding-page-jumps), so that the space for image is occupied.

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet given below:

```
$(".carousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var $active = $(this).find('.carousel-indicators').find('li.active');
    fixLazyLoadCarousel($active);
});
function fixLazyLoadCarousel($active) {
    var $targetImage = $($active.data('target')+" .carousel-inner").find(".item:eq("+$active.data('slide-to')+")").find('img');
    var src = $targetImage.data('src');
    if (typeof src !== "undefined" && src != "") {
        $targetImage.attr('src', src)
        $targetImage.data('src', '');
    }
}
```

See the Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/51fLLtq2/20/